# Generating a text file with jasperReporting

Tags: jasper-reports

this is my code java to generate a txt file with jasper :

```
package sms;

import module.User_Excel;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.Exporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleTextReportConfiguration;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleWriterExporterOutput;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main_txt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println( "generating jasper text file [.txt]" );

            // Define the parameter for the user name
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("userName", "salma");

            // Compile the JasperReport template
            File template = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:template_txt.jrxml");
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(template.getAbsolutePath());

            // Fill the JasperPrint object
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params, new JREmptyDataSource());


            // Export the JasperPrint to a text file
            Exporter exporter = new JRTextExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleWriterExporterOutput("output.txt"));
            SimpleTextReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleTextReportConfiguration();
            configuration.setPageWidthInChars(80); // Set the page width to 80 characters
            configuration.setCharWidth((float)8); // Set the character width to 8 pixels
            exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);

        exporter.exportReport();



            System.out.println("Report generated successfully!");

    }
    public static JRDataSource getDataBeanList() {


        List<User_Excel> users = new ArrayList<User_Excel>();
        users.add(new User_Excel("salma abou", 22, "salma.abou@email.com"));
        users.add(new User_Excel("Jane Doe", 25, "jane.doe@email.com"));

        return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(users);

    }
    private static JasperReport getJasperReport() throws FileNotFoundException, JRException {
        File template = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:template_txt.jrxml");
        return JasperCompileManager.compileReport(template.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    private static Map<String, Object> getParameters(){
        String userName = "salma aboumzrag";
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("createdBy", "salma");
        parameters.put("userName", userName);
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

and here is my template :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="HelloUser" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="userName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="24"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Hey, " + $P{userName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

i need to generate a text file saying Hello {user_name}
Igot ths error :

**Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Character height in pixels or page height in characters must be specified and must be greater than zero.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter.initReport(JRTextExporter.java:301)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractExporter.setCurrentExporterInputItem(JRAbstractExporter.java:616)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter.exportReportToWriter(JRTextExporter.java:328)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRTextExporter.exportReport(JRTextExporter.java:206)
at sms.Main_txt.main(Main_txt.java:50)**

Comment: Hey welcome to SO! Could you try to delimit where your problem could be? Don't expect people to just read your whole code and tell you where the problem is. Instead, debug and find out where your code fails. Try some stuff to fix it. Then, if nothing else works, share a snippet of your concrete problem

Answer (score 0):

i have to remove the **font size="24"** from my template because it- is not compatible with my config

Comment: I m talkin about the :  <font size="24"/>